# Meteor Key Up event

Tags: javascript, meteor

I was using

#### Template.foo.rendered

```
$(document).keyup(function(e){
  code here
})
```

But now I'm trying to use this!!

#### Template.foo.events

```
'keyup .overlay': function(e) {
    if (e.keycode == 27) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(".overlay").removeClass('overlay-open');
        $(".overlay").addClass('overlay-hide');
    }
}
```

However, it won't work... Any ideas?

Comment: Wouldn't it be `e.keyCode` (capital C)?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
'keyup .overlay': function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 27) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(".overlay").removeClass('overlay-open');
        $(".overlay").addClass('overlay-hide');
    }
}
```